# Ember get the JSON response of a POST request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, ember-data

I have a Ruby On Rails API and a front end in ember apart.
I'm trying to add a record from ember to my api. I can see in my api logs that my request is well executed and return a json. But in my ember app i try to print that JSON response and access to those informations..

here's the code from my controller to create a record from my ember app :

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {

    submit: function(){
      var result = this.store.createRecord("session", {email: this.get('email'), password: this.get('password')});
      var onSuccess =  function(post){

        console.log("kikou");
        console.log(post);
      };

      var onFail =  function(post){
        console.log("kikou");
        console.log(post);
      };

      result.save().then(onSuccess, onFail);
    }
  }
```

the JSON returned is :

```
{"user":{"email":"gui@hotmail.com","authentication_token":"4vLAkiM1Ro5qN2HeNogM","id":1}}
```

How can I access to email, authentication_token etc...?
Maybe I'm doing something wrong or it is not the proper way to create a record on my rails api?

I do not want to make any ajax code in my controller otherwise I do not see any interest to use Ember.

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

You should have a model `user` defined, as well as use the [`DS.ActiveModelAdapter`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.ActiveModelAdapter.html) for your Ember application:

**app/models/user.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  authentication_token: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Then, on the `onSuccess` function you can access the data like this:

```
var onSuccess =  function(post){
  console.log(post.get('id'));
  console.log(post.get('email'));
  console.log(post.get('authentication_token'));
};
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said but when I make `post.get('id')` it prints `null` and for `post.get('authentication_token')` it prints `undefined` but the email is printed.

Comment: Can you put up a jsbin or similar to reproduce the problem?